Bulk SMS Dynamic URLs without Headers failing DLT India
I'm having trouble with our bulk SMS campaigns. It looks like there’s been a change in TRAI guidelines I found here that now requires us to include specific headers in dynamic URLs for compliance.
I checked out existing vendors like Bitly, Rebrandly, but they don’t support adding custom headers to the short links, which is a must for us to avoid our messages getting flagged as spam.
Does anyone know of a service or a workaround that allows me to create short URLs with custom headers? I need something that complies with the TRAI regulations. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I fixed this. I had received the following update from fast2sms
You need to whitelist all URL (website links) which you're sending inside SMS on DLT Portal before 01/10/2024 else your SMS will fail.
Watch this video: https://youtu.be/uajYj0bAM18
The video will give you more context. This is due to the new TRAI guidelines.
I found Smler- https://app.smler.in. It provides custom headers, as its new, it seems to have good customer support if you run into any issues.
